# Is there a way I can count bounces from a ball in OpenCV?

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv, computer-vision

I made a ball tracking program using this guide: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/09/14/ball-tracking-with-opencv/

I wanted to ask if there is a way I can tell how many bounces a ball makes in a certain time. Or even any method I can use to count the bounces of the ball on the ground, because I intend to use the program to track someone doing basketball dribbling training. Thank you in advance :)

I want to make something similar to this: https://youtu.be/OMXYvkryF1I at 2:26

Here is my code if it helps:

```
# import the necessary packages

from collections import deque 
#list like data structure will keep prev positions of ball 
#can make a trail of the ball from it 

import numpy as np
import argparse
import imutils 
#this is that guys list of Opencv stuff he uses - got resizing and all - can use pip to get it 
#$ pip install --upgrade imutils

import cv2
import time


# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",
    help="C:/Object_detection/models-master/research/object_detection/test_images/multi_angle.mp4") 
#can put path to video here. That is if it is there
#if not there the program will just use the webcam

ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer", type=int, default=64,
    help="max buffer size")
# this tells max size of deque which is the list with points 

args = vars(ap.parse_args())


##Put lower & upper boundaries of colour 
#colourLow = (0, 135, 30)
#colourHigh = (19, 255, 255)


#Put lower & upper boundaries of colour 
colourLow = (0, 135, 30)
colourHigh = (19, 255, 255)
pts = deque(maxlen=args["buffer"]) #initialises our deque points

# if a video path was not supplied, grab the reference
# to the webcam
# item that tells if we using a video or webcam
if not args.get("video", False):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #imutils.Video stream item works good with webcam 

# otherwise, grab a reference to the video file
else:
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"]) #this is if the video is supplied


    
#Loop for video frame capturing
while True:
    #calls the read method in our capture module 
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    #if we were running a video from external source and no other frame was taken again for processing
    #it means we reached end of video so we break out of loop
    if frame is None:
        break

    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=800) #smaller frames means faster processing so we resize
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (11, 11), 0) #blur reduces picture noise to allow us to see stuff more clearly 
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) # converting frame to HSV

    # we now masking to get the desired colour only
    # we do erosion, dilation and removal of blobs
    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, colourLow, colourHigh) #locates our object in the frame
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2) #erosion
    mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2) #removal of blobs

    # Will draw outline of ball and find (x, y) center of ball
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]   #this makes sure contour will work on all opencv items 
    center = None #make the coords of the ball 0 at first 

    
    if len(cnts) > 0:     # only proceed if at least one contour was found
        # finds largest contour mask, then uses this to get minimum enclosing circle and center
        c = max(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)
        ((x, y), radius) = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(c)
        M = cv2.moments(c)
        center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))  #this & above line get centre coords
        

        # only proceed if the radius meets a minimum size
        if (radius > 30): 
            # draw the circle and centroid on the frame,
            # then update the list of tracked points
            cv2.circle(frame, (int(x), int(y)), int(radius),
                (0, 255, 255), 2)
            cv2.circle(frame, center, 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
            
        
    # update list of points
    pts.appendleft(center)

    # loop over set of points 
    for i in range(1, len(pts)):
        #if we don't have tracked points we should ignore them 
        if pts[i - 1] is None or pts[i] is None:
            continue

        ickk = int(np.sqrt(args["buffer"] / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)

        def drawline(img,pt1,pt2,color,thickness=ickk,style='dotted',gap=20):
            dist =((pt1[0]-pt2[0])**2+(pt1[1]-pt2[1])**2)**.5
            pts= []
            for i in  np.arange(0,dist,gap):
                r=i/dist
                x=int((pt1[0]*(1-r)+pt2[0]*r)+.5)
                y=int((pt1[1]*(1-r)+pt2[1]*r)+.5)
                p = (x,y)
                pts.append(p)

            if style=='dotted':
                for p in pts:
                    cv2.circle(img,p,thickness,color,-1)
            else:
                s=pts[0]
                e=pts[0]
                i=0
                for p in pts:
                    s=e
                    e=p
                    if i%2==1:
                        cv2.line(img,s,e,color,thickness)
                    i+=1

        #if we do we will draw point connecting line 
        #gotta define the thickness first
        thickness = int(np.sqrt(args["buffer"] / float(i + 1)) * 2.5)
        #cv2.line(frame, pts[i - 1], pts[i], (0, 0, 255), thickness)
        drawline(frame,pts[i - 1], pts[i],(0, 0, 255),thickness)

    # show the frame to our screen
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break


# cleanup the camera and close any open windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: If you can consistently track the ball then you can maintain its velocity by comparing it's current position to it's previous position. Any time that velocity changes direction you can tell that it has bounced. i.e. if it suddenly changes from going down, then hits the ground and starts moving up, you'll register that as a bounce.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverflow. kindly try to explain the question on the main part itself. **The question should be written so that it makes sense even if the links break or change.** Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a clear idea of how to ask a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I set up a simulation to show what I was talking about in the comments. Basically, every time the camera takes a picture (whatever fps your camera runs at) you can get the ball's position. Using that position you can estimate velocity (change in position divided by time). If there's a sudden change in the direction of that velocity then you can count that as a bounce.

[image]

The vast majority of this code is for setting up the simulation and can be safely ignored for your purposes. Here's the relevant code block

```py
    # check if it's time for a snapshot
    camera_timer += dt; # time since last snapshot
    if camera_timer > (1.0 / camera_fps):
        # estimate velocity
        est_vel[0] = (ball_pos[0] - prev_pos[0]) / camera_timer;
        est_vel[1] = (ball_pos[1] - prev_pos[1]) / camera_timer;

        # check if the sign of the velocity has changed
        if sign(est_vel[0]) != sign(prev_est_vel[0]) or sign(est_vel[1]) != sign(prev_est_vel[1]):
            # check for bounces from large change in velocity
            dvx = abs(est_vel[0] - prev_est_vel[0]);
            dvy = abs(est_vel[1] - prev_est_vel[1]);
            change_vel = math.sqrt(dvx*dvx + dvy*dvy);
            if change_vel > bounce_thresh:
                bounce_count += 1;

        # update previous state trackers
        prev_est_vel = est_vel[:];
        prev_pos = ball_pos[:];

        # reset camera timer
        camera_timer = 0;
        snap = True;
```

And here's the entire thing if you want to play with the simulation yourself

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time
import math

# get mouse click
click_pos = None;
click = False;
def mouseClick(event, x, y, flags, param):
    # hook to globals
    global click_pos;
    global click;

    # check for left mouseclick 
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        click = True;
        click_pos = (x,y);

# return sign of number
def sign(val):
    if val > 0:
        return 1;
    if val < 0:
        return -1;
    return 0;

# create blank image
res = (600,600,3);
bg = np.zeros(res, np.uint8);
display = np.zeros(res, np.uint8);

# set up click callback
cv2.namedWindow("Display");
cv2.setMouseCallback("Display", mouseClick);
click_force = 1000;

# font stuff
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX;
fontScale = 1;
fontColor = (255, 100, 0);
thickness = 2;

# make a ball
ball_radius = 20;
ball_pos = [300,300];
ball_vel = [0,0];

# set physics
drag = 0.98;
bounce_mult = 0.95;
grav = -9.8; # acceleration in pixels per second
time_scale = 5.0;

# register click animations
click_anims = [];
anim_dur = 0.25; # seconds
anim_radius = 20; # pixels

# track bounces
prev_pos = ball_pos[:];
est_vel = [0,0];
prev_est_vel = [0,0];
bounce_count = 0;
bounce_thresh = 10; # velocity must have a sudden change greater than this magnitude to count
camera_fps = 24; # we'll only take snapshots at this speed
camera_timer = 0; # time since last snapshot
snap = False;
pic_count = 0;

# loop
done = False;
prev_time = time.time();
while not done:
    # refresh display
    display = np.copy(bg);

    # update timestep
    now_time = time.time();
    dt = now_time - prev_time;
    dt *= time_scale;
    prev_time = now_time;

    # update physics
    # position
    ball_pos[0] += ball_vel[0] * dt;
    ball_pos[1] += ball_vel[1] * dt;

    # velocity
    ball_vel[1] -= grav * dt;
    drag_mult = (1 - ((1 - drag) * dt));
    ball_vel[0] *= drag_mult;
    ball_vel[1] *= drag_mult;

    # check for mouse click
    if click:
        # register animation
        click = False;
        click_anims.append([time.time(), click_pos[:]]);

        # get dist
        dx = ball_pos[0] - click_pos[0];
        dy = ball_pos[1] - click_pos[1];
        dist = math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);

        # clamp dist
        if dist < 1:
            dist = 1;

        # get force attenuation
        # force = click_force / (dist*dist); # too much
        force = click_force / dist; 

        # get angle and get axial force
        angle = math.atan2(dy, dx);
        xforce = math.cos(angle) * force;
        yforce = math.sin(angle) * force;

        # apply force
        ball_vel[0] += xforce;
        ball_vel[1] += yforce;


    # check for bounce
    # left
    if ball_pos[0] - ball_radius < 0:
        ball_pos[0] = 0 + ball_radius;
        ball_vel[0] *= -bounce_mult;

    # right
    if ball_pos[0] + ball_radius > res[0]:
        ball_pos[0] = res[0] - ball_radius;
        ball_vel[0] *= -bounce_mult;

    # up # +y-axis is down in OpenCV
    if ball_pos[1] - ball_radius < 0:
        ball_pos[1] = 0 + ball_radius;
        ball_vel[1] *= -bounce_mult;

    # down
    if ball_pos[1] + ball_radius > res[1]:
        ball_pos[1] = res[1] - ball_radius;
        ball_vel[1] *= -bounce_mult;

    # check if it's time for a snapshot
    camera_timer += dt; # time since last snapshot
    if camera_timer > (1.0 / camera_fps):
        # estimate velocity
        est_vel[0] = (ball_pos[0] - prev_pos[0]) / camera_timer;
        est_vel[1] = (ball_pos[1] - prev_pos[1]) / camera_timer;

        # check if the sign of the velocity has changed
        if sign(est_vel[0]) != sign(prev_est_vel[0]) or sign(est_vel[1]) != sign(prev_est_vel[1]):
            # check for bounces from large change in velocity
            dvx = abs(est_vel[0] - prev_est_vel[0]);
            dvy = abs(est_vel[1] - prev_est_vel[1]);
            change_vel = math.sqrt(dvx*dvx + dvy*dvy);
            if change_vel > bounce_thresh:
                bounce_count += 1;

        # update previous state trackers
        prev_est_vel = est_vel[:];
        prev_pos = ball_pos[:];

        # reset camera timer
        camera_timer = 0;
        snap = True;

    # draw bounce text
    cv2.putText(display, "Bounces: " + str(bounce_count), (15,40), font,
                fontScale, fontColor, thickness, cv2.LINE_AA);

    # draw ball
    x, y = ball_pos;
    cv2.circle(display, (int(x), int(y)), ball_radius, (220,150,0), -1);

    # draw click animations
    for a in range(len(click_anims)-1, -1, -1):
        # get lifetime
        life = now_time - click_anims[a][0];
        if life > anim_dur:
            del click_anims[a];
        else:
            # draw
            mult = life / anim_dur;
            radius = int(anim_radius * mult);
            if radius > 0:
                val = 255 - int(255 * mult);
                color = [val, val, val];
                cv2.circle(display, click_anims[a][1], radius, color, 2);

    # show
    cv2.imshow("Display", display);
    key = cv2.waitKey(1);

    # # if snapshot, save a picture
    # if snap:
    #   snap = False;
    #   cv2.imwrite("bouncy/" + str(pic_count).zfill(5) + ".png", display);
    #   pic_count += 1;

    # check keypresses
    done = key == ord('q');
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!! I get what you mean, I'll try implement it and tell you how it goes

Comment: Do you mind if I send you a piece of code to guide me on how I can manipulate the points to implement this bounce counter? I was adding more features then I got to a point where it wasn't counting anymore :|

Comment: you should post another question asking for help with your problem.

Comment: This answer should get more votes. Great work! :) What you do?